# Javascript does not change property value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm using IE and creating a web form using visual studio.

I'm trying to change the value of style of a toast i've created.

The toast html is taken from here : http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_snackbar

my html code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/snakebar.css" type="text/css" />


<style type="text/css">
    #s3 {
        display: none;
    }

    .s {
        display: none;
    }

    .s2 {
        display: compact;
    }
</style>

<button onclick="myFunction()">CLICKER</button>
<div id="snackbar" class="show">
    Some text some message..
   <%-- <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Some text some message.."></asp:Label>--%>



<script>

    function myFunction() {

        var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
        if (x != null) {

            if (document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility == "hidden") {

                try {
                    document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    // document.getElementById("snackbar").className.replace("show", "s");
                    // document.getElementById("snackbar").className.value = "s3";
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("snackbar").className.value = "show";
                window.onload = function () {

                    document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

When i press the button i always get "" in style.visible instead of "visible" or hidden.
any ideas? Thank You!

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I THINK you meant to do this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility = "visible";

  document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
    if (x != null) {
      var vis = x.style.visibility;
      x.style.visibility = vis == "" || vis == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="but" type="button">CLICKER</button>
<div id="snackbar" class="show">
  Some text some message..
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the updated, more unobtrusive version

Comment: Thank you!
Do you know by any chance to do the same think by code behind. I'd like to call the javascript function :  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
It does work, but the visiblity status stays the same always

Comment: function myFunction() {
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("snackbar").style.visibility = "visible";

                document.getElementById("but").onclick = function () {
                    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
                    if (x != null) {
                        var vis = x.style.visibility;
                        x.style.visibility = vis == "" || vis == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Do NOT put window onload inside a function - it has to be outside. Also no need to put it into codebehind. It will execute on load